# Missing body and unfounded error message on IE9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9

I have a social network that allows users to post [blogs](http://cysticlife.org/Blogs.php) and ask [questions](http://cysticlife.org/Questions.php). If you click on the above links, you'll notice a commnunity blogs and questions page where the authors posts' are displayed.

If you look on FF,Safari,Chrome, or IE8 you'll see them displayed as they should. If you look on IE9, you see giant black letters underneath the body that say "Object Not Found!". Another major issue is that when I ask a question in IE9, the body of the question does not display on the community page OR on the actually blog when you have it opened to read. ( so does not display at all).

Which is even MORE curious, is that when composing a blog is WORSE on IE9. When submit is pressed, it just reloads the page blank. The code structure for composing blogs and questions, and displaying blogs and questions is EXACTLY the same except mysql differences.

All of the above works as it should on IE8, FF, Chrome, and Safari etc...

Here is the lengthy code structures for each: ( it is quite a bit so I am going to put links to the code hosted somewhere else )

[Compose Blog](https://gist.github.com/ca05d73f7aa7963778e3)

[Community Blogs Page](https://gist.github.com/e099a9e324c045f67866)

[Reading Individual Blog](https://gist.github.com/2ef2c90cac1fe81d255d)

// DUPLICATE PAGES BUT JUST FOR QUESTIONS :

[Ask a Question](https://gist.github.com/0710ed4d975fc11d4214)

[Community Questions Page](https://gist.github.com/728619a6cfdb1fe5f528)

[Reading Individual Question](https://gist.github.com/7755b346b60f49dd6748)

It is quite a bit, I'm just stabbing in the dark at this point and really am not sure how to fix this. Is it the java script I have on the page, is there some sort of syntax style I'm using that is not rendering? really no clue

Please help before IE makes me choose another career ;)

Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddy you have JS error here and there .

In IE8 and FF 3.6 i got error.

JS error will cause  chain reaction. If one fails everything fails.

Check that coda_slider_filter.js

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks. can you tell me which page you are seeing the coda_slider on? I took it off the blogs pages. thanks man

Comment: mind is boggled. really confused as to how your seeing the 'coda_slider_future.js' on the all blogs page

Comment: You should use Firebug Firefox addon you will see everything

Comment: I did. My error console is yielding NO errors and the source code and my script files do NOT have 'coda_slider_future.js'